# Terminology to describe bell rope

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for words that describe the rope that hangs from a bell in a bell tower.

ADDED: This isn't so much about where the word would be used as it is trying to identify examples or variations from literature or other reference to the item.

The nautical reference below is one scenario where there might be other terms to fit the description. I thought there may also be a reference from the religious sector (though Bell Rope and Bell Pull seem to fit here).

I would even be interested in slang as noted below, "Go jig the bell". Thanks for that.

Comment: ***Bell rope*** is correct: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bell-rope

Comment: don't thinks that's it ... and no answering questions in comments.

Comment: @Cascabel was not aware of such sentiment  - but explains a lot.

Comment: Vote to leave open. It's easy enough to imagine that there might be a special term for such a rope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bell-pull#bell-pull__1) says **bell pull**

> a rope that you pull to make a bell ring

Not that it makes a whole lot of difference.  My G-mother always said 'go jig the bell.!

Comment: A good point, but I normally associate 'bell pull' with an old style doorbell.

Answer (score 4):

**Rope** appears to be the correct name.

Here is a [glossary of bellringing terms](http://www.cb1.com/~john/ringing/glossary.html), and the rope is referred to as a 'rope' throughout.

Comment: Even when it's on a boat, it's one of the few that don't magically turn into a line.

Comment: You have a boat with a bell tower on it?